# using commander.js in node for command line apps?

Tags: node.js, shell, command-line

I'm trying to build a command line app using NPM module commander.js.

[Commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/)

With commander.js you get to run your commands on the terminal like this:

```
$ ./app --help
```

But i want to convert this into:

```
$ app --help
```

How can I achieve this, I'm going to release this to the NPM registry. Does it happen automatically or do i have to change something.

Note: The file name of the shell script is `app`!

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. I think it's a fairly simple question. The answer is once you release it to the NPM registry, then install it *globally* using `npm install -g foo.js`. Once installed globally you'll be able to launch it from any path without typing `./` first. This is common with development tools you'd need available across projects, such as [ESLint](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) or [Grunt Complexity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-complexity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running file as:

```
./app --help
```

means the file is in current directory, so you are saying run app file which is in current directory.
But if you have "." which is current directory in env variale:`$PATH`, you dont need to mention `./app --help`, you can simply say `app --help`, as shell knows where to find that file.

If you want to add current directory in path do:

```
export PATH=$PATH:.
```

If you need more information and explanation [please check here](http://technonstop.com/dot-slash-meaning-linux).

Hope this clarifies your query.

Comment: This is not the right answer. Considering the script is a Node module and that the question specificies the package will be available from the NPM registry, the right answer would be that installing the package globally will make it available from anywhere and remove the need to type `./` ahead of it.